# SFSafariViewController done button not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, nsurl, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have a test `ViewController` which is embedded in a `NavigationController`. In test `ViewController` I have a `WebView` button. When I click on that `button` it navigates to `SafariViewController` and it's loading given URL. In that `WebView` when I click on "Done" button it's calling delegate method called `safariViewControllerDidFinish`. But that `SafariViewController` is not being dismissed.

Here is my code.

```
- (IBAction)bannerWebviewAction:(id)sender {
    NSURL *urls = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    SFSafariViewController safariVC = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:urls];
    [self showViewController:safariVC sender:nil];
    safariVC.delegate = self;
}

#pragma SFSafariViewControllerDelegate
-(void)safariViewControllerDidFinish:(SFSafariViewController *)controller {
    // Done button pressed
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];  
}
```

Done `button` is calling, view is not dismissing. I checked log for the `self` and `controller`, both are correct.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should not say

```
[self showViewController:safariVC sender:nil];
```

You should say

```
[self presentViewController:safariVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

SFSafariViewControllers are meant to be presented modally and will dismiss itself when done is pressed.